# HBase: reading directly from MemStore

Tags: hbase

I'm trying to (programatically) get a quick count of the `KeyValues` in an `HTable`. For each of the table's `HFiles`, I get an `HFile.Reade`r and call `getEntries()`.

I still need a way to determine the number of `KeyValues` in the `MemStore` for each region of the table. Looking at the `MemStore` interface, I see a `keySize()` method to get the amount of heap storage for KVs, so I guess I could use that to derive an estimate.

I was wondering if there was a way to access the in-memory data that hasn't been flushed to an HFile in the same way that an `HFile` is directly read. Does the structure of the `MemStore` follow that of an `HFile`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what version of HBase you are using, but looking through my cloudera source I [see](https://github.com/cloudera/hbase/blob/55d6a01/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/MemStore.java#L546-L554) `getScanners()`, which will give you a scanner to iterate through the key values.

Alternately you might try `snapshot()` and `getSnapshot()`, whose result exposes a `size()`.

Notice you'll need to inject your own class into the package for either of these tricks to work.